# It leads to unauthorized result in my API when i am Changing the default table "users" linked with auth in laravel,

Tags: laravel, authentication

**When i am trying to change the table users, that is by default linked with the Auth in laravel my API always gives me "unauthorized user" response  and when i use the default table user it works fine. I want to know why it is happening?**

I have made all the changes that is required to switch the table from users to my choice table.

my table name is : apitable, Model_name: apitablemodel

changes in auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'Passwords' => 'apitable',               //if want to change the table attached with auth then make changes here
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [ 
        'web' => [ 
            'driver' => 'session', 
            'provider' => 'apitabel', 
        ], 
        'api' => [ 
            'driver' => 'passport', 
            'provider' => 'apitable', 
        ],


    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
         'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'apitable' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\apitablemodel::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
         'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'apitable' => [
            'provider' => 'apitable',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**Here is my model file**

```
 <?php

namespace App;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class apitablemodel extends Authenticatable
{  use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    //
    protected $table='apitable';

    protected $fillable = ['Email', 'Password','token'];
    public $timestamps=false; 
    protected $hidden = [
        'Password', 'token',
    ];
}
```

**Here is my controller file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\apitablemodel;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
// response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
class product extends Controller
{  public $successStatus = 200;
    public function login(Request $request){ 


      if(Auth::check(['Email' => request('Email'), 'Password' => request('Password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
         $user->token=$success['token'];
        //  $token->expires_at=Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
         $user->save();

         return response()->json(["token_expires in :"=>"2min","token"=>$user->token]); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 

    }
    public function update(Request $req){


    $obj= User::find($req->id);
    $obj->email=$req->email;

    if($obj->save()){

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Updated']); 
    }

else{
    return ["status:"=>"Unauthorized user, make sure your are login"];
}

    }
}
```

I have two functions in my controller, one is for updating the data that is present in the "apitable" table and one for login so that only authenticated users can update the database table values.

When i hit my API in postman it gives me unauthorized response as for which i have write the condition in my controller. I want to know why if condition is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Auth::attempt()` method for login.

```
 public function login(Request $request){ 

    $credentials = $request->only('Email', 'Password');
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        $user->token=$success['token'];
        //  $token->expires_at=Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(["token_expires in :"=>"2min","token"=>$user->token]); 
    } else { 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    }
```

Comment: I have tried attempt , but  it gives an error that "Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt doesn't exist"  that's why i changed it to check